# ¿Por qué automáticamente WooCommerce indica que un usuario ha comprado un producto?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

Tengo una función que me indica cuántos de cierto producto, ha comprado el usuario logueado.

El problema viene cuando al mostrar el resultado, me indica que el usuario ya lleva 15 comprados.

Esto no es una cantidad que le pase yo a la función.

La función es esta:

```
cuantos_ha_comprado(){
    global $product, $post;
    $orders = get_posts( array(
      'post_type' => 'shop_order',
      'post_status' => 'wc-completed',
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'posts_per_page' => '-1',
      'author' => $current_user->ID
    ) );
    //print_r($orders);
    $el_contador = 0;
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
       $order = new WC_Order( $order->ID );
       $items = $order->get_items();
       foreach( $items as $item ) {
         //print_r($item);
        $id_del_producto = $item['product_id'];
        if ( $id_del_producto == '1211' ):
          $el_contador = $el_contador + 5;
        elseif ( $id_del_producto == '1212' ):
          $el_contador = $el_contador + 10;
        elseif ( $id_del_producto == '1213' ):
          $el_contador = $el_contador + 25;
        elseif ( $id_del_producto == '1214' ):
          $el_contador = $el_contador + 50;
        elseif ( $id_del_producto == '1215' ):
          $el_contador = $el_contador + 100;
        elseif ( $id_del_producto == '1216' ):
          $el_contador = $el_contador + 200;
        elseif ( $id_del_producto == '1218' ):
          $el_contador = $el_contador + 300;
        elseif ( $id_del_producto == '1230' ):
          $el_contador = $el_contador + 10;
        endif;
    } 
} 
return $el_contador;
}  

En el otro archivo, donde llamo a la función, pongo:
// Con esto establezco el límite de posts que puede hacer el usuario
$cuantos_compro = cuantos_ha_comprado();
$le_quedan_para_hacer = $cuantos_compro - $lleva_creados;
```

Una solución que encontré, fue poner **return $el_contador - 10**

Pero no ayudó en mucho, ahora tendría que poner *-15*
No se si esto sea debido a un error de configuración de Woocommerce, o es que tengo un virus, no lo se.

Comment: ¿Porqué haces en $el_contador incrementos de +5, +10, +25 y demás en lugar de +1? Otra cosa, dudo que un virus sea tan selectivo que haga cambios en una función php que has hecho tu, lo más probable es que esté mal hecha.

Comment: Uh no entiendo bien la idea de sumar los productos entre sí indistintamente. Según ese bucle bastaría que un usuario hubiese comprado un producto 1211 y uno 1212 y ya sumaría 15. ¿Estás intentando hacer una descomposición polinomial en otro lado?

Comment: 1. El comentario del virus es porque la función me indica la cantidad de productos que ha comprado. Así que pensé que un virus puede afectar esa cantidad.
2. El motivo de sumar es que los productos representan paquetes de pases. Entonces necesito saber en total cuántos pases ha comprado el usuario, de tal modo que pudo comprar un paquete de 5, y 2 de 10 pases, teniendo así un total de 3 productos comprados pero equivalentes a 25 pases.

Comment: Es decir, ¿el producto con id 1211 es en realidad 5 productos ya que se trata de un pack de 5?

Comment: Correcto. Es un pack de 5 pases

Comment: Veo que en algún momento, has mostrado un print_r de $orders y $items, ¿Puedes añadir el resultado de estas variables a tu pregunta?